# How to calculate distance when given two sources of time and speed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

A bus traveling between $2$ towns arrives $7$ minutes late when traveling $40$ mph. When traveling $36$ mph, the bus arrives $22$ minutes late. What is the distance between the two towns?

Here's what I did:

$x=$ original time

$40(x+7) = 36(x+22)$
$x=128$, so when you substitute $x$ for one of the expressions, you get $40(128+7)=5400$, so 5,400 miles?

Comment: You're using incompatible units: miles per hour versus minutes.  Either convert the miles per hour into miles per minute, or convert the minutes into hours.  Then you should get the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your methodology is generally correct. However, note that if you are considering:
$$40(x+\color{red}{7})=36(x+\color{red}{22})$$
Then you are considering the delay to be $7$ and $22$ hours, not minutes.
Therefore, you must solve the following:
$$40\left(x+\frac{7}{60}\right)=36\left(x+\frac{22}{60}\right)$$
Giving the answer for $x$ in **hours**. Then, you can do the same as you've done before (Substitute $x$ into one of the expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the way you set things up, $x$ is a number of minutes (which you can see when you notice that we are adding $7$ or $22$ minutes to $x$).   So you correctly deduced that $x$ is $128$ **minutes** and then went astray by multiplying a number of miles per **hour** times a number of minutes.

What you should have done in the last step is to multiply $\frac{40}{60}$ miles per minute by $128+7$ minutes, getting an answer of $90$ miles.

Answer (score 0):

First note that $40$ mph$=\frac 23 $m/min and $36$ mph $=\frac 35$ m/min.

Let $D$=distance between towns, and $T$ =time taken for journey to get to destination on time.

Using distance [m]= speed [m/min] $\times$ time [min], we have

$$D=\frac 23 (T+7)=\frac 35 (T+22)\\
D=\frac {\overbrace{2T+14}^P}{\underbrace{\;\;\;3\;\;\;}_R}=\frac {\overbrace{3T+66}^Q}{\underbrace{\;\;\;5\;\;\;}_S}=\frac {\overbrace{132-42}^{2Q-3P}}{\underbrace{10-9}_{2S-3R}}=\color{red}{90}$$
using linear componendo and dividendo.